How to workaround the CSS-Houdini Paint Worklet causing an error with pagespeed insights?
Why is it when I attempt to use a CSS Houdini Paint API worklet, I get this error from pagespeed insights:
Oops! Something went wrong.
generic::internal: Empty extension result. RenderingException: [EXTENSION_ERROR]
As seen on this page:
https://www.datafault.net/qhtml/dashboard.html
Whereas if I remove the CSS-Houdini Paint API specifically the CSS.paintWorklet.addModule() function,  pagespeed has no problems.
After removal of CSS Paint API addModule:
https://www.datafault.net/qhtml/dashboard2.html
Everything works.
It doesn't even matter if I first perform rudamentary checking to try to prevent the script from executing if the CSS Paint API is not supported.
How can I get around this? Is this  a bug with pagespeed?
I attempted to add in wrappers around the import statement, but it did not work and pagespeed still fails
    <script type="module">
if (window.CSS !== null) {
    if (CSS.paintWorklet != null) {
                CSS.paintWorklet.addModule("tech-panel-worklet.js");
            }
    }
    </script>
            

I was expecting pagespeed to not continue attempting to import the paint worklet.
The page loads without errors under other browsers and other pagespeed tools.
